# Adding a link from an image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This seems to be more difficult than it should be.
All I would like to be able to do is add a link from an image on my wordpress site to an external website.

Using the normal media library tools this doesn't seem to be possible so I got the plugin `WP Gallery Custom Links`

However, even though I added the external link to the Gallery Link URL it still doesn't link.

Is there a more straightforward way to embed a link into an image?

Here is a screenshot of the image editing page:

[image]

Comment: Where are you trying to add the link to? Do you want the image to be an actual link, once clicked on it will bring you to an external site?

Comment: Hi @ jerseyetr yes that is correct- I want the image to be a link to an external website.

Comment: Please see my Answer below. There are 2 ways listed. Both should achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make an Image clickable and bring you to an external site, click the image, click Edit, under Display settings select link to, custom url, and there you go.

Another way is, when you are adding an image to your site from your Media Library within Wordpress, there is an option "Link to" under Attachment Display Settings.

Comment: Hi @jerseyetr So the problem is that I have no 'Link To' to allow this to happen- see the screenshot I have added to the question

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Was there no Link to option before or after installing this plugin? and is the Image a standalone image or one within a post?

Comment: I never had a link option even before adding the plugin. The image is as part of a post